# Count observations arranged in multiple columns

Tags: r, count, subset

I have a database with `species` ID in the rows (very large) and places where they occur in the columns (several sites). I need a summary of how many `species` are per site. My observations are categorical in some cases (present) or numerical (number of individuals), because they are from different database sources. Also, there are several `na`'s in the entire database.

in R, I have been using functions to count observations one site at the time only.

I appreciate any help on how to count the observations from the different columns at the same time.

Comment: Some sample input and output would go a long way in helping you get an answer....

Answer (score 0):

You could do just:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tables
  WHERE conditions
```

And in the conditions specify the different columns conditions

```
  WHERE t.COLUMN1="THIS" AND t.COLUMN2="THAT"
```

or with a SUM CASE (probably the best idea in general):

```
 SELECT grfield, 
 SUM(CASE when a=1 then 1 else 0 end) as tcount1,
 SUM(CASE when a=2 then 1 else 0 end) as tcount2
 FROM T1
 GROUP by grfield;
```

Or in a more complex way you could do a subquery inside the count:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT D
      FROM T1
      INNER JOIN T2
      ON A.T1=B.T2
    ) AS subquery;
```

You could do also several counts in subqueries... the possibilities are endless.